# How about to delete cell using the if function

Tags: function-keys

I cant to delete cell with the if function.
The my homework a must have the if function to do delete cell.
Help me, please!.
example: =IF( cell F5="[trongthuycanh](http://trongthuycanh.net)" then delete cell F5,uchange);

what's wrong in the function.

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward initial note: formulas cannot actually DELETE cell content.

Formulas may refrain from displaying a value though. Example: having F5 contain this formula:

> =IF(E5="Not valid";"";"Text or formula to show or use when valid")

... where E5 set to `Not valid` would show F5 as empty - or alternatively:

> =IFERROR(100/E5;0)

Which would display `0` instead of `#DIV/0!` for a zero in E5

Take note that cell content (formula, text, date, numbers, ...) is always present in a cell, and will not change by any other means than by scripting (VBA, Python, ...) or your typing.

At the same time you may DISPLAY the content in a formatted way (tip: hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and hit <kbd>1</kbd> and look around), so that e.g. numbers have a specific number of decimals, or dates display only as year and month or a year and week number.

*Note: above you see `;` used as separator between function arguments, you might have to use `,` - this depends on your locale settings (Language and Country).*